# How to use two href in single anchor tag

Tags: javascript, java, html

I did this way its executing `printInvoice` only, but I'm unable to execute PrintOrder, I want to execute both by just single clicking submit

```
<a href="PrintInvoice?invoiceID=<s:property value="invDetail.arInvNum"/>"
   href="PrintOrder?orderID=<s:property value="ordDetail.orderID"/>"> submit
</a>
```

Comment: Could you please provide your complete Code or other information. With this information no one can know what you want to do, nor where is the error.

Comment: Find a different way to achieve your goal, having a duplicated href attribute for an Anchor tag won't work and isn't valid.

Comment: Did you try  using the javascript function `onclick()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call two separate functions on click of submit.

Let's assume submit is a button.

You can call two separate functions on click of submit.

Let's assume submit is a button.

```
<button onclick="printInvoice('<s:property value='+invDetail.arInvNum+'/>');printOrder('<s:property value='+ordDetail.orderID+'/>');">Submit</button>
```

You can do similar for anchor tag you have used.

your functions might be:

```
function printInvoice(invoiceId){
    document.location.href = "PrintInvoice?invoiceID="+invoiceId;
}

function printOrder(orderId){
    document.location.href = "PrintOrder?orderID="+orderID;
}
```